# PHP can't write to error log - permission denied

Tags: php

In my first PHP script in many years, I'm trying to log an error:

```
error_log("my error message", 3, $error_log);
```

I'm getting an error in the general Apache error log:

> PHP Warning:  error_log(/var/log/apache2/my_php_errors.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/blahblah/my_script.php on line 88

This is what I've checked and tried:

- Created `$error_log` with the same ownership (`root.adm`) and permissions (`640`) as the Apache error log.
- Changed the owner to `www-data`, which is the user PHP is running as.
- `log_errors` is `On`.
- `open_basedir` is not set.
- Using PHP 5.5.x, so safe mode does not exist.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** It's able to write to the general Apache error log.  The mystery is why it can't write to another file in the same directory with the same ownership and permissions.

**Edit 2:** Another developer told me that this works on his WAMP, so it's something specific to my LAMP stack or config.

Comment: We need more info on `$error_log` variable. It's the destination towards the log file. Leave it empty for a default log file. For example, is it in or outside the web root directory. If outside you might want to check the allowed include path in the ini.

Comment: Contact your server admin.

Comment: Try using 777 for files that PHP needs to write to and see if that works

Comment: @frosty I am my own server admin.

Comment: @Xorifelse It's exactly the file in the PHP error message.

Comment: Also, make sure selinux is disabled. People always forget that one

Comment: @Machavity Same error with 777.  I'm developing on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition, which does not have selinux.  Would apparmor affect this?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Wasn't there when I commented. Since it's outside your webroot it is most definitely a permission issue. Do you run multiple websites, if not just leave out the `$error_log` variable so apache can use the default one. If you really want your own file try changing the permissions of that file with `chmod +xa /var/log/apache2/my_php_errors.log` or run it recursively on the folder.

Comment: @Xorifelse I already described how I changed the permissions of that file.  Anyway, why would I want it to be executable?

Comment: @Machavity, you should not disable selinux. If selinux is blocking something, then you should set context appropriately instead.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
https://serverfault.com/questions/831444/php-error-log-per-vhost/831666#831666

```
touch /path/to/php_error.log
chown www-data:www-data php_error.log
chmod 755 php_error.log
```

thanks for leading me to the answer!

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would have worked in my case, since I tried setting the owner to `www-data` and the permissions to the even broader `777`.  Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the environment where I encountered this problem.

Comment: PHP (or apache2) needs to have the ability to create and write a file in the directory.  I had no problems by putting the log file in html directory, but I did not want the error_log file in the public viewable directory... Also, I did not want to broaden the scope of the virtual server root directory.. so I created the file in the root (touch), then set the broader permissions on just the file for it.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**:  check that all the ancestor directories allow reads/lists by the web server.

On my system, my equivalent of `/var/log/apache2/my_php_errors.log` was giving this same error.  I eventually did an `ls -ld` at every level of the path (`/`, `/var/`, `/var/log/`, `/var/log/apache2/`, `/var/log/apache2/my_php_errors.log`).

Four of those had permissions that made them readable by the web server.  One of them, `/var/log/apache2/` did not.  When I moved my file out of the `apache2` directory, everything started working.  E.g. `/var/log/php/` and set appropriate permissions/ownership (e.g. 750 by www-data.adm) on the new directory.

```console
prompt> ls -ld /var/log/php/
drwxr-x--- 2 www-data adm 4096 Nov  1 13:31 /var/log/php/
```

You could also change the permissions on `/var/log/apache2/`, but that seems like a security/privacy issue.  It's safer to make a new directory and leave the existing structure as is.

The reason why the permissions have to change is that it is no longer using some version of [`syslog`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6409729/6660678) to publish to the log files.  The `syslog` variants run as root and accept messages from non-root.  But in my case, I was specifying the file from the web server, which made the permissions wrong.

There is a [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25233789/6660678) that uses `syslog` so that it could keep the same ownership.  I did not try to make that work, as this is for a test server.

This may not have been the problem that you were having, but I'm pretty sure that I was using the default permissions for `/var/log/apache2/`.  So it's quite possible that it was the problem.  And even if it wasn't, this is one of the places I was searching for troubleshooting advice.  So next time something like this happens to me, I'll have a reminder of what to check.

Answer (score 0):

Give ownership to all parent directories by using the -R flag:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /var/www/html/dir1/dir2/dir3/
```